# PSAT install on Matlab for MAC

Tags: macos, mac, matlab

Hi anyone knows how to install PSAT on Matlab on Mac computers?
I have installed and running already Matlab 2015b.
A guide would be great.
Thanks in advance

[image]

My steps was:
to put the entire psat folder including all the package's .m files into the toolbox folder within the matlab root which can be seen in the picture. I have then reopened matlab and opened a new script, looked around, opened simulink, but I have not been able to start up the psat toolbox. Is there a specific way in which I need to access the toolbox while on matlab? 
Sorry for the basic question

Answer (score 0):

The latest PSAT version(2.1.9) works with 2014a.
PSAT has issues with matlab version 2014b and higher. Might be because it(version 2.1.9) was released not long after 2014b, and so it may not be updated for the system changes made in R2014b and higher.
For PSAT i would recommed 2014a. Since you are using a mac, you will want to install a JAVA patch (from: http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1098655) for 2014a(or older) due to a Java exemption error because of which you wouldn't be able to start matlab after installation.

Installing PSAT: After you download and extract:

- 1. Click Setpath in MATLAB
- 2. Click Add with subfolders and save.

Hope this works